# Close Windows on TextBox text change using Mvvm, Wpf,C#,Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to execute a method on TextChange event and for specific text, I want to do something and close the window using MVVM

for example on this part of my code I want to close my window:

```
if (text.Equals("12345"))
{
   //Exit from window
}
```

I know how can I do it from a button using a command, As I have in the code of the next example.

But how can I pass the window to a running property that binds to a text of the textbox?

or there is another way to close form?

I want to do it on the ViewModel and not the code behind to write my code as MVVM pattern close that I can

my XAML code :

```
<Window x:Class="PulserTesterMultipleHeads.UserControls.TestWindows"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PulserTesterMultipleHeads.UserControls"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Name="MainTestWindow"
        Title="TestWindows" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>

            <TextBox Text="{Binding Text,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>

            <Button Command="{Binding EndTestExit}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MainTestWindow}">Exit</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

the code behind XAML :

```
using PulserTesterMultipleHeads.Classes;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace PulserTesterMultipleHeads.UserControls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for TestWindows.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class TestWindows : Window
    {
        public TestWindows()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new TestWindowsMV();
        }
    }
}
```

View Model code :

```
using PulserTester.ViewModel.Base;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace PulserTesterMultipleHeads.Classes
{
    public class TestWindowsMV : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string text;
        public string Text {
            get {
                return text;
            } set {
                text = value;
                if (text.Equals("12345"))
                {
                    //Exit from window
                }

            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        ///  for the example
        /// </summary>
        private ICommand _EndTestExit;

        public ICommand EndTestExit
        {
            get
            {
                if (_EndTestExit == null)
                {
                    _EndTestExit = new GenericRelayCommand<Window>((window) => EndTestExitAction(window));
                }
                return _EndTestExit;
            }
        }

        private void EndTestExitAction(Window window)
        {
            window.Close();
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

*************************  Edit as the answer ****************************
The change in ModelView :

```
public string Text {
            get {
                return text;
            } set {
                text = value;
                if (text.Equals("12345"))
                {
                    CloseAction();
                }

            }
        }
```

The change in code behind:

```
public TestWindows()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new TestWindowsMV();

            if (((TestWindowsMV)DataContext).CloseAction == null)
                ((TestWindowsMV)DataContext).CloseAction = new Action(this.Close);

        }
```

Comment: As workaround, you can make you close button invisible/disabled by default and enable it only when text in textbox meets your condition. Don't forget to fire `propertychanged` (currenly your `Text` property doesn't have it)

Comment: Is the window parameter variable? Why don't you set the window as a property within your View Model and just call `EndTestExitAction(Window window)` from the conditional in your setter?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I want this hidden button to shot automatic when the right string is coming..   it is possible?

Comment: There is nothing against using the TextBox.TextChanged event to close your Window. On the other hand everything within MVVM is against having reference to your VIEW in the ViewModel. ViewModel should be separated and it should be working without a View. If you unit test your current ViewModel it will fail.

Comment: @NawedNabiZada  MVVM doesn't mean to separated my logic to my view?

I have the login in my ViewModel and view on the window

Comment: Yes but your ViewModel should work regardless of what View does or looks like. In your particular case you have a reference to view (Window) in your VM. that is not allowed

Comment: @NawedNabiZada You mean this line : CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MainTestWindow}" ?

Comment: This one:  private void EndTestExitAction(Window window)
        {
            window.Close();
        }

Comment: @NawedNabiZada It is the only way that I know to close the window...

Comment: @jon: Try to set the TextBox.TextChanged event. Check your condition in the eventhandler and call this.Close();

Comment: @NawedNabiZada I did as the answer of Bibipkins said..
I don't want to do my logic on TextChanged event in code behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is kind of hard with MVVM but what you can do is create an Event inside of your ViewModel and attach a function that will close your window in code behind of your View. Then you will be able to call your event inside of ViewModel whenever you need to close the window (or do something else that is more convenient to do in View rather than in ViewModel)

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to close a View from the ViewModel is to use an attached property

```
public static class perWindowHelper
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CloseWindowProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "CloseWindow",
        typeof(bool?),
        typeof(perWindowHelper),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, OnCloseWindowChanged));

    private static void OnCloseWindowChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (!(target is Window view))
            return;

        if (view.IsModal())
            view.DialogResult = args.NewValue as bool?;
        else
            view.Close();
    }

    public static void SetCloseWindow(Window target, bool? value)
    {
        target.SetValue(CloseWindowProperty, value);
    }


    public static bool IsModal(this Window window)
    {
        var fieldInfo = typeof(Window).GetField("_showingAsDialog", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        return fieldInfo != null && (bool)fieldInfo.GetValue(window);
    }
}
```

which you can then bind to an appropriate property in your ViewModel

```
<Window
    x:Class="...

    vhelp:perWindowHelper.CloseWindow="{Binding ViewClosed}">



private bool? _viewClosed;
public bool? ViewClosed
{
    get { return _viewClosed; }
    set { Set(nameof(ViewClosed), ref _viewClosed, value); }
}
```

More details on my recent [blog post](http://peregrinesview.uk/mvvm-navigation/).

Answer (score -1):

You have almost everything you need already implemented. All you really need to do is call `private void EndTestExitAction(Window window)` from your setter and supply `window` its value during construction:

```
public string Text {
            get {
                return text;
            } set {
                text = value;
                if (text.Equals("12345"))
                {
                    EndTestExitAction(window)
                }

            }
        }
```

where `window` is a property of your View Model.

Comment: Not MVVM, bad practice!

Comment: How is this not within MVVM? The view is setting the text through the view model, the view model calls a method within itself which acts on the view.

Comment: ViewModel does not know anything about View... You should separate those layers. View knows ViiewModel, but ViewModel doesn't know anything about the view

Comment: I suppose you're right in that, mixed up with Presenter. But still, how is one supposed to close a window through MVVM then? Even with the command approach (currently implemented through the button), the view model knows and controls the view outside of binding.

Comment: One of the biggest mistake people make when it comes to MVVM is that they think code behind is not allowed. You can still use code or events like Button.Click, TextBox.TextChanged as long as it is View logic. Anything with Model logic should go through ViewModel with bindings